# Error dehydrating property value with fluent Nhibernate with bit

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have this class:

```
public class Person
{
   public virtual long     ID            { get; set; }
   public virtual string   FirstName     { get; set; }
   public virtual string   LastName      { get; set; }
   public virtual boolean  IsValid       { get; set; }
}
```

and person data mapping:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
    {
        public PersonMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.ID);
            Map(x => x.FirstName).Not.Nullable().Length(100);
            Map(x => x.LastName).Not.Nullable().Length(100);
            Map(x => x.IsValid).Not.Nullable();
        }
    }
```

And this is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,    
    [IsValid ] [bit] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I insert a new `Person` in the database using Fluent NHibernate but we got this problem:

```
error dehydrating property value for `NameSpaceA.IsValid`
```

And inner exception:

```
_innerException = {"Invalid index 2 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=2."}
```

Comment: Can you post the table that this class maps to ?

Answer (score 2):

As Jamie Ide said, try explicitly mapping the Id as generated by identity, but also check and see if removing the .Not.Nullable() from the IsValid mapping allows it to work. Since in c# the type is boolean it can never be null anyway.

```
public PersonMap()
{
    Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.FirstName).Not.Nullable().Length(100);
    Map(x => x.LastName).Not.Nullable().Length(100);
    Map(x => x.IsValid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the full error message and stack trace. This is an error message that is often misleading in that other errors occurred prior to this one.

I'll hazard a guess that the root cause is that you have not declared a generator for the ID property. The fact that it's typed as long may also be an issue. How are you generating/setting the ID property?

Assuming that you're using an identity column (int), the mapping would be:

```
Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
```

Comment: The "invalid index" error message is usually (always?) caused by a duplicate mapping. Carefully check your mappings to ensure that you haven't mapped a column more than once.